# php- how to use explode feature by number of character?

Tags: php

I create code for the divide the paragraph of string by " ".
but now i want to divide the paragraph or string by number of character.

```
<?php
$pizaa="this is my line"
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces;
?>
```

In above code how to divide this line by number of character.not using `wordwrap()`.
only using the `explode()`.

Comment: What's wrong with wordwrap() ?

Comment: Is this code copied exactly? Are you aware you have spelt `$pizaa` and `$pizza` differently?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or puzzle or something?

Answer (score 1):

use `str_split()` to explode by number of character.

```
<?php
$pizaa="this is my line";
$pieces = str_split($pizaa);
var_dump($pieces);
?>
```